# Cardboard-xr-plugin causes the VR environment to stutter when moving the camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr

When running the sample project 'HelloCardboard' from [Google VR cardboard-xr-plugin](https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard-xr-plugin) on my Samsung Galaxy S9 (API Level 29) the view stutters when I look around (move the camera) in VR. This wasn't a problem when I used the [old Google SDK](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk) on Unity 2019.4 in my own project.

I'm using Unity 2020.1

To make sure that it was not a performance issue, I have tested the following:

- removing all assets from the demo scene, except for the camera and a simple plane
- creating a new project with the cardboard xr plugin installed, without importing the 'HelloCardboard' demo scene

Since this didn't make a difference regarding the stuttering, I tried running the app after I:

- installed a different SDK (which shouldn't be a problem but still)
- changed the Graphics API from OpenGLES2 to OpenGLES3

None of this worked.

Does anyone know what (might) cause the stuttering? Or know where I can find the solution? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try to deploy app to another smartphone?
2. Did you try new plugin-in Unity 2019.4?
3. Did you try to use 'Mono' Scripting Backend?